# jquery on toggle content area moves below shown area

Tags: jquery, mobile, toggle

I'm trying to replicate the facebook mobile website where you click a menu button and the left menu appears. The issue I'm having is that I want my width of my content area to be 100 percent, but when the hidden menu shows the 100 percent content area drops below the menu.

Here's the js fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/EssVx/)
Code is shown below.

Thanks in advance for any responses

HTML

```
 <div id="menu">
 </div>
 <div id="content">
     <div id="header">
         <div id="menuButton">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>​
```

CSS

```
 body{padding:0px; margin:0px; width:100%; min-width:320px; height:100%; min-height:480px; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
 #menu{ width:240px; min-width:240px; height:100%; min-height:480px; float:left; background-color:#CCCCCC; display:none; position:relative;}
 #header{ height:48px; width:100%; min-height:48px; min-width:320px; background-color:#666666;  float:left;}
 #menuButton{ width:30px; height:30px; background-color:#999999;margin-top:9px; margin-left:15px;}
 #content{ float:left;  min-width:320px;  min-height:480px; width:100%;}
```

jQuery

```
 $("#menuButton").click(function () {
     $('#menu').toggle(),750;
 }); ​
```

Comment: What does this mean? '100 percent content area drops below the menu.'

Comment: It looks like your fiddle is working...can you explain a little more? Maybe add different background color to help explain what you are looking to do?

Comment: in the fiddle, the header that contains the button drops under the menu, I just want it to move to the right by 240px. I've updated the fiddle to show the content area as grey to show the content area is moving down rather than right.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my hosting has been down so I haven't been able to get the file up, I'll update with a link as soon as its back on.

Comment: I actually have this working now, thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prevents the horizontal scroll bar from popping up, also, pads the top so the content actually shows.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/EssVx/8/)

```
    $("body").on('click', '#menuButton', function () {

        if($('#container').position().left === 0){
            $('#container').css({'left' : 240 , 'width' : $('#container').width() - 240 } );
        }else{
            $('#container').css({'left' : 0, 'width' : '100%'});
        }

        $('#menu').toggle();
    });
```

Comment: That's definitely sorted the header but the grey content area still drops below.

Comment: @huddds So you want the content to be under the menu? or move over like the header?

Comment: @VIDesignz you were almost correct just that you need to wrap `#header` and `#content` in another div and apply the script to them. Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EssVx/5/)

Comment: @huddds Revised answer...prevents horizontal scroll from popping up and pads the content on the top to actually show the content

Comment: @AndreiR +1 Thanks man, I wasn't sure exactly what he was going for...again, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @VIDesignz this is exactly what I'm after, doesn't seem to be doing anything when I click the button, I've added the exact code from the fiddle. Any ideas?

Comment: @huddds Can you send a link to your page?

Comment: @huddds Did you copy the css from the fiddle as well?

Comment: Yeah, the html, script and CSS, it just does nothing on the browser, I'm using jquery 1.8.2, the page is currently local but I'll add a link as soon as I get home.

Comment: @huddds That is strange.. I have updated the jquery to use the .on() handler, this may help. Also, are you wrapping the code in an onload function? ie; $('document').load(function(){ 'Do Stuff Here...' }); ?? If not, make sure the script is at the end of the page, right before the </body> tag, and wrapped in <script type='text/javascript'></script>  On a side note...In the css, I forgot to add the semicolon at the end of the width:100% on two elements. Make sure to change it, I updated my fiddle to represent all the changes I mentioned here.